# Swagger Maven Plugin doesn't generate operations and models

Tags: java, maven, swagger

I have a Spring Boot app and use Swagger Maven Plugin from https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin

The configuration in pom.xml is below:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <apiSources>
                    <apiSource>
                        <attachSwaggerArtifact>true</attachSwaggerArtifact>
                        <outputFormats>json</outputFormats>
                        <locations>package.with.apis</locations>
                        <schemes>
                            <scheme>http</scheme>
                            <scheme>https</scheme>
                        </schemes>
                        <host>localhost:8083</host>
                        <basePath>/api</basePath>
                        <info>
                            <title>Your API name</title>
                            <version>v2</version>
                            <description>Description of your API</description>
                        </info>
                        <swaggerDirectory>generated/swagger-ui</swaggerDirectory>
                    </apiSource>
                </apiSources>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

`<locations>package.with.apis</locations>` is the package containing all the interfaces tagged with `@Api`

`<swaggerDirectory>generated/swagger-ui</swaggerDirectory>` is the directory where the generated `swagger.json` lands

But the generated `swagger.json` doesn't contain the information in `@ApiOperation, @ApiResponses`, DTO models etc.

It seems to contain only the values of `@Api(tags = {"API ..."})`

Below is the excerpt from it:

```
{
  "swagger" : "2.0",
  "info" : {
    "description" : "Description of your API",
    "version" : "v2",
    "title" : "Your API name"
  },
  "host" : "localhost:8083",
  "basePath" : "/api",
  "tags" : [ {
    "name" : "API 1",
    "description" : ""
  }, {
    "name" : "API 2",
    "description" : ""
  }, {
...
```

What am I missing? How should I configure it properly so that it generates a JSON that describes the API completely comparable with what we usually see at `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` endpoint?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you manage to resolve the issue?

Comment: @Satishkumarsahu No. I gave up. Our team decided to extract the corresponding JSON from a running service (endpoint `/swagger-resources`) and deploy it in Nexus. We've delegated all the work to automate this to DevOps.

Comment: I have been trying to figure out the solution for last 2-3 days, I noticed that while doing mvn compile, --- swagger-maven-plugin:3.1.7:generate step was not picking up my classes, then I came across this link https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin/issues/611 , the guy was facing the exact same issue, I tried the solution, worked for me!! Hope this helps.